# Adding date and time to a field

Tags: salesforce

I have a field in a custom object with type datetime. And need to fill the field with day from a another field and time as '8:00 AM' est

for eg: the field value should look like - 2012/05/01 8:00 AM

please help me to find the solution 
Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 0):

This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, but you'll want to use a formula field, probably along with the `DATE()` function to grab the date from the date field and then you can add the time on manually, I can't provide any more detail with more detail on what you're filling it from.

If you've not joined it already there is an [Area 51 Proposal for a Salesforce Q&A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce?referrer=4-k5FqV679TWbBGLxdLUKg2) for exactly this type of question.

Comment: but last 3 times i got the answer for the doubts. May i know why this is out off topic. (I have also tag the salesforc).

Comment: Because stackoverflow is for programming related problems, although you could do this with code on Salesforce the best way to do it would be with a formula field instead. It's because people were closing questions like this that I created a proposal for a Salesforce site :)

Comment: Thanks LaceySnr, I have resisted in the Area 51. But not able to ask my doubts it says need at least 5 reputation to past question. What should be done ?

Comment: You can't actually ask and get answers on the Area 51 proposal yet, we need to get enough people committed with a good score on other sites (such as this one) and then it'll go live which means we can all use it and benefit!